# Converting checkbox to select (perl)

Tags: perl, forms, mojo, mojolicious

Before:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='killerFeature' id='killerFeature' 
    <%= param('killerFeature') ? ' checked' : ''%> 
/>
```

Now:

```
<select name="killerFeature" id="killerFeature" class="select">
    <option value="1">Enable</option>
    <option value="0">Disable</option>
</select>
```

How do I insert the same checked (should be 'selected' now I guess?) condition in the select now?

This is a perl app, built using Mojolicious web framework.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the condition should be selected (selected="selected") but i belive you already figured that out from your other post :)

```
<select name="killerFeature" id="killerFeature" class="select">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Enable</option>
    <option value="0">Disable</option>
</select>
```

Also from what i saw there inst a way to create the select like you can for the input as in the below example:

```
<%= input 'test', type => 'text' %>
```

So it would be something like:

```
<%== param('killerFeature') eq $my_var ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; %>
```

Ofc you would need to replace the above to your current variables and field names.

GL:)

Comment: W3C requires there to be a left and right hand.  Instead of 'selected' it should be 'selected="selected"'.